# R plot saving - chance the default suggested plot name

Tags: r, plot, save

when I save a plot in R, I would like to see the name of the previously saved ones. Is there a way to do that? In 
this example below,

[image]

the suggested name is Rplot. I'd like to have an easy way to see the previously stored plots and their names. Or eventually, used the last used name as the suggested one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save the plot with `ggsave()` instead of manually trying to save every time.

```
ggsave('plot.png', plot = p, width = 15, height = 10)
```